# How to push from Masterview to detail view with storyboard?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uistoryboard

i tried to push to detail view in storyboard, but is not working.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"drinkList"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [self.drinksCatTable indexPathForSelectedRow];

        if (myIndexPath.row ==0) //if selected is row 1 
        {
            selectedDrinkCat  =[segue destinationViewController];
            Drinks *drinkList = [aDelegate.categoryArray objectAtIndex:0];//forward all drinks to drinksList
            selectedDrinkCat.drinkList = drinkList;//point drinkList to the next view drinkList
            selectedDrinkCat.allDrinkStr = @"All";//all drinks selected 
                 NSLog(@"aaa");
        }
        else 
        {
            Drinks *drinkList = [aDelegate.categoryArray objectAtIndex:(myIndexPath.row)-1];//we have to minus 1 as the row had en extra "All" row which is not in the database
            selectedDrinkCat.drinkList = drinkList; 
            selectedDrinkCat.allDrinkStr =@"cat";
            NSLog(@"1111");

        }
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"drinkList" sender:self];
    NSLog(@"called did select");   

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't you declare `selectedDrinkCat` as a `viewcontroller` of the class of the `destinationViewController`?

Something like:

```
desmondViewController *selectedDrinkCat=(desmondViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the view controller's `pushViewController:` method.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

- Go to the `storyboard` file
- click on `viewcontroller1` then press on the main viewcontroller (mouse + ^) and drag it to the `viewController2`
- from the context menu select push
- a link will be created between these views, click on it and in the inspector change `Indetifier` to `drinkList`

This sets up the storyboard

Now the code you written should work.